# Cordova app with Cordova GoogleMaps Plugin on IBM MobileFirst Platform

Tags: java, cordova, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I’m just starting to  use IBM MobileFirst Platform(MFP).
Does anyone know how to  use Google Maps on Cordova app with MFP?

When I tried to add the  MobileFirst Cordova SDK into the existing application, I got an error because  of out-of-scope cordova versions.
Cordova versions on my app  are:
- cordova-android: 4.1.1  (requirement: >=5.1.1 <6)
- cordova-ios: 3.9.2 (requirement:  >=4.1.1 <5)
And my app is using  Cordova GoogleMaps Plugin.
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps
The version is  1.3.9(stable), which does not support cordova-ios 4.x.
On the other hand, Cordova  GoogleMaps Plugin(1.4+) can support cordova-ios 4.x but is unstable.
So when my app can use  Google Maps, it cannot use MFP.
Also when it can use MFP,  it cannot use Google Maps.

Are there any solutions to  solve it, except for waiting until the stable version of Cordova GoogleMaps  Plugin becomes 1.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You also asked this in the MobileFirst Slack community and received your question...

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1-based Cordova apps use Cordova 3.6.
MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 now supports standard Cordova apps and the minimum supported version of the ios and android Cordova plug-ins match the requirements.

You can use v8.0 to create Cordova applications that match your requirement.

Comment: I understand that MFP 8.0 supports the version of Cordova on my app.  
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try using embedded maps in an iFrame.
There's no usage limits for the Google Maps Embed API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

This is how I did a search for nearby restaurants.

```
<iframe
     id="map"
     width="600"
     height="450"
     frameborder="0" style="border:0"
     src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=<key>&q=restaurants&zoom=13" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```